# Display list of artifacts inside confluence page

Tags: artifactory, confluence

I have a list of artifact which I can see as JSON list:
http://artifactory.server/artifactory/api/storage/my-folder

and I want to display them in a Confluence page.

Is there a Macro? Maybe JS option?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your user case the best way to add/update content in Confluence is using [Confluence Server/Cloud REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api).

You can send your list to a Confluence page or create a new page, for example, in every release version from your CI(Jenkins, Bamboo...).

Comment: thanks for the answer, it's a good idea but my privilege are not allow me to do so. I can only read from artifactory and update pages in confluence inside the system. I am not an admin

Comment: @aviram83 as a normal user is more complicated but you can do a Selenium script, for example.